# How to get a path out of an NSSavePanel object in Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I have been attempting to use the NSSavePanel to save text files in a program written in Swift. The only issue is that every time I attempt to use the URL attribute, it has a nil value. Yes, I have a folder selected and a file name in the input when testing. Here's my code:

```
    let saveDialog = NSSavePanel();
    saveDialog.beginWithCompletionHandler() { (result: Int) -> Void in
            if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
                let file = NSFileHandle(forWritingToURL: saveDialog.URL!, error: nil)!;
                for match in Globals.matches {
                    if let data = (match.toString() as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                        file.writeData(data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    // other setup code not shown
```

When I run this, I always get the Swift equivalent of a null-pointer exception on the

```
let file = NSFileHandle(forWritingToURL: saveDialog.URL!, error: nil)!;
```

line. Can I please have some help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: you don't need to put the `;` at the end of the semicolon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation for `NSFileHandle(forWritingToURL:error:)`, it says:

> The initialized file handle object or nil if no file exists at url.

So this only works if the file already exists. Which is probably not what you want.

It looks like `NSFileHandle` cannot create new files at all, so I would just use the following before you try to open the file:

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    .createFileAtPath(saveDialog.URL.path, contents: NSData(), attributes: nil)
```

Which will create an empty file, which you can then open and write your data to.